# Python selenium unable to click field

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to request data that I can later scrap. I write the dates in the text field but when I send the request, it does not update according to the dates. I'm trying to click the date field, but I don't see the calendar pop up as it should. How can i go about this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar')

time.sleep(10)

#close popup
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@aria-label="Close Modal"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('fxit-advlink').click()

#click filter options
driver.find_element_by_id('fxit-advlink').click()

#set start and end time
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'fxit-start-advance')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'fxit-start-advance')]").send_keys("01/01/2017")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'fxit-end-advance')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'fxit-end-advance')]").send_keys("06/01/2017")


#select countries

#select data type
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="fxst-selectall" and @data-name="fxst-category"]').click()

#refresh your results
driver.find_element_by_id('fxit-filterbutton').click()
```

Comment: No need to click before sending keys. you can comment those lines

Answer (score 0):

I'd double check that you are correctly selecting the elements you want. This might not be the case as you mentioned not seeing the date-time picker.

I'd recommend using the Selenium IDE (download link on their website [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)). It's a plugin for Firefox which allows you to record actions against a page. That way you could compare against what you have.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works correctly for me. I am able to see the calender open and input the date.
One point - you may want to include a .clear() between your .click() and .send_keys() as the input box does not automatically clear - this may be why you are not seeing your date update if there is validation looking for a correct date format.