# Selenium problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping

I'm clicking the date box, clearing the values and requesting for new data. I'm trying to click the date field, but I don't see the calendar pop up as it should. How can i go about this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/usch/Desktop/PyCharm/Project/geckodriver')

#load up website
driver.get('https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar')

time.sleep(10)

#close popup
popup = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@aria-label="Close Modal"]')
popup.click()

#click filter options
filter = driver.find_element_by_id('fxit-advlink')
filter.click()


#set start and end time
startDate = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'fxit-start-advanced')]")
startDate.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
startDate.clear()
startDate.send_keys("01/02/2017")
startDate.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

endDate = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'fxit-end-advanced')]")
endDate.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
endDate.clear()
endDate.send_keys("06/01/2017")
endDate.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

#driver.switch_to.default_content()
#select countries

#select data type
category = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="fxst-selectall" and @data-name="fxst-category"]').click()


#refresh your results
refresh = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="fxit-filterbutton"]').click()
```

Comment: the calendar is showing and disappearing very fast cuz well it's selenium it has to make things go fast, but do you want to like wait and see it for a while ?

Comment: even if i run it line by line, the calendar doesn't pop up

Comment: i added time.sleep(5) after each time setting, it popped correctly so i don't think it's related to your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python selenium unable to click field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907291/python-selenium-unable-to-click-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the locator as when you try to run the above code it throws error "element not clickable other element would receive click"

Just add  `execute_script()` in your code it will work

> ## Also never use a reserved keyword in your coding as filter is a keyword in python

```
filter1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#fxit-advlink')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", filter1)

category = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="fxst-selectall" and @data-name="fxst-category"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", category)

#refresh your results
refresh = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="fxit-filterbutton"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", refresh)
```